# selectButton and click with Goutte scraper PHP

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, goutte

I need to click a "View more" button on my page, but it is not a form, it is a button type "button".

My code looks like this:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.xxxx.com');
$button = $crawler->selectButton('View more');
$client->click($button);
```

This returns:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client::click() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Link, instance of Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\index.php on line 17 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\vendor\symfony\browser-kit\Client.php on line 238

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

> A selectButton() method is available on the Crawler which returns
> another Crawler that matches a button (input[type=submit],
> input[type=image], or a button) with the given text.

Actually, that is what the error is saying: the parameter received by `click()` is a `crawler`, when it should be a `Link`. I'm not familiar with goutte **scraper** , but have you tried with:

```
$button = $crawler->selectButton('View more')->button();
$client->click($button);
```

Answer (score -1):

This method ->button() is private we can't access.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).